# Angular2 Setting up ng2-dragula (Instructions Incomplete)

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am using Angular2 RC1 and I've install NG2-Dragula from [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula):

In the documentation for setup on the link all it says you need to do to get it working is:

> You'll need to add DragulaService to your components viewProviders and
>   also add Dragula to your components directives.

But adding Dragula for the directives area on my component will not get it to work as I'll get error: `Unresolved variable or type Dracula` ... It will at least need an import right?

Does anyone know how to set ng2-dragula up because the instructions are incomplete?

Comment: Yes, import the Providers and Directives with `import {Dragula, DragulaService} from 'ng2-dragula';`

Comment: I added: import {Dragula, DragulaService} from 'ng2-dragula'; but it returns error: Cannot GET /ng2-dragula

Comment: Did you install it with npm?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's installed

Comment: You could try `import {Dragula, DragulaService} from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula.js';` and add a reference to `ng2-dragula.d.ts` from the same folder.

Comment: import {Dragula, DragulaService} from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula.d.ts'; seems to stop errors in the component itself BUT at runtime I get: Cannot GET /ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula.d.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113544/discussion-between-rinukkusu-and-estevan-gomez).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `systemjs.config.ts` you have to add a few things.

To the `map` variable:

```
'ng2-dragula':                'node_modules/ng2-dragula',
'dragula':                    'node_modules/ng2-dragula'
```

and to `packages` add:

```
'ng2-dragula': { main: 'ng2-dragula.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

This will tell SystemJS where to look for your packages.

Comment: This helped with my `app.module.ts` but still cannot import the following in my component: `import {Dragula, DragulaService} from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';` - it complains about `Dragula` AND `@Component { directives: [Dragula] }` isn't valid.  Trying to follow these instructions: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/wiki